# What does it mean with numerous equal signs whtin a console.log request

Tags: console.log

What does this console.log expression code mean: equal signs within quotes within the, such as: console.log("===============================")? is the number of equal signs significant?

Comment: It's just a line separater. Used as a visual indication to gruop log lines in a hige chunk of logs.

Answer (score 0):

None. It is just for pretty printing, to indicate like a start or end of a segment to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think its for visual Separation.

The number is not significant.